# How to add a custom process template to TFS 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am new to TFS. Can any one tell the steps to add a custom process template to TFS 2013?

Comment: Do you already have the custom template and just want to upload it to TFS or are you asking about customising templates in general.  If so, what do you want to customise?

Comment: Already i have a custom template. I want to apply this template to TFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open Visual Studio, click the Team menu
- Select Team Project Collection Settings
- Select Process Template Manager
- Click Upload
- Navigate to the folder that contains the ProcessTemplate.xml file for
  your custom template
- Click Select Folder

If your template passes validation then it will appear on the list when you create a new Team Project
[image: Process Template Manager]

Upload, download, and delete process templates for a team project collection
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181510.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try the following steps.

Step 1 – Install Process Editor
open process editor in visual studio.(TOOLS->Process editor)

Step 2 – Choose the Process Template

Step 3 – Download the Process Template

Step 4 – Open the Process Template in Process Editor

Step 5 – Modify Work Item Types

Step 6 – Modify the Default Work Items

Step 7 – Modify and Manage Queries

Step 8 – Modify Areas and Iterations

Step 9 – Modify Groups and Permissions

Step 10 – Modify Source Control Settings

Step 11 – Modify the Project SharePoint Portal

Step 12 – Modify Reports

Step 13 – Upload the Modified Process Template